# Perl's rename: GATES, Bill -> Bill Gates

Tags: perl, rename

Suppose I have files named like `GATES, Bill.jpg` and I want to rename them all to `Bill Gates.jpg`. I can capture the two words

```
rename 's/^(.*?), (.*?)\./$2 $1\./g' *
```

To change a case there are some Perl's functions:

```
$lower = lc("aBcDe");  # $lower is assigned "abcde" 
$upper = uc("aBcDe");  # $upper is assigned "ABCDE"
$lower = lcfirst("HELLO");  # $lower is assigned "hELLO" 
$upper = ucfirst("hello");  # $upper is assigned "Hello"
```

I tried to make use of them:

```
rename 's/^(.*?), (.*?)\./$2 ucfirst($1)\./g' *
```

But it doesn't work.

Comment: I've written a [bash wrapper](https://github.com/bk322/bk-goodies/blob/master/bk-renames.bash) for Perl's rename - which previews renames - and if You accept it - only then it does rename.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to add the "e" (eval) flag to the end of the regular expression, otherwise the function won't be executed. This means that the entire second part of the `s///` expression has to be a valid Perl expression (instead of a valid string):

```
rename 's/^(.*?), (.*?)\./"$2 " . ucfirst(lc($1)) . "."/ge' *
```

(also note the extra space inside the string with `$2`)

More information on this flag can be found in the `perlre` documentation.

Comment: Well done. +1  Now the regex is a working statement, although I am at a loss as to how this code will be used.

Comment: This is the "rename" (sometimes called "prename") command, which is part of the Perl distribution. It's a simple/short Perl script that renames all files specified on the command line by applying a Perl expression.

Comment: I see, well that makes sense then. Another way to go is using the escape sequences: `s/(.+?), (.+?)\./\u\L$2\E, \u\L$1\E/`. Then you will not need to use evaluation (although I am not sure which is better in this case). `\u, \U, \l, \L` are equal to ucfirst, uc, lcfirst, and lc respectively. See [perlreref](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlreref.html#FUNCTIONS) for more information.

Answer (score 4):

Should be:

```
rename 's/^(.*?), (.*?)\./$2 \u\L$1./g' *
```

Although that doesn’t always work perfectly on Unicode.  For those few corner cases it misses, you would want something more like

```
rename 's/^(\w)(\w*),\s+(\w+)\./$3 \u$1\L$2./g' *
```

Here’s where you can get a [somewhat updated version of the regular *rename* program](http://training.perl.com/scripts/rename).

Comment: Which way it is updated? I'd like to know - to take advantage.

Comment: As a moderately related question, would it make more sense to capture a grapheme for the first letter? I don't know any greek, but the COMBINING GREEK YPOGEGRAMMENI case makes me wonder.

Comment: @Hugmeir: Sometimes it might, but not in this instance. ᴄᴏᴍʙɪɴɪɴɢ ɢʀᴇᴇᴋ ʏᴘᴏɢᴇɢʀᴀᴍᴍᴇɴɪ is already lowercase. Even if you grabbed `\X`, applying `\u` to it would only titlecase the head of the grapheme, which can virtually never be ᴄᴏᴍʙɪɴɪɴɢ ɢʀᴇᴇᴋ ʏᴘᴏɢᴇɢʀᴀᴍᴍᴇɴɪ. The exception would be the defective case of it following a linebreak grapheme, which it is not allowed to combine with. Then titlecasing it would produce a ɢʀᴇᴇᴋ ᴄᴀᴘɪᴛᴀʟ ʟᴇᴛᴛᴇʀ ɪᴏᴛᴀ. But it isn’t “supposed” to be in that position, really. That is the only cased code point in `Grapheme_Extend`.

Comment: @Adobe: Use the src, and see.